# Simplifying an equation

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I need to differentiate $y = t^2\ln(4t)$ which i understand needs to be done using the product rule.

I know that $u = t^2$ and $v = \ln(4t)$

and $du = 2t$ and $dv = \frac{1}{t}$

So $u\,dv + v\,du = t^2\frac{1}{t} + \ln(4t)2t$

I have simplified $t^2\frac{1}{t}$ down to $t$

I am a bit confused of what i can do to $\ln(4t)2t$

Thanks

Comment: A tutorial for MathJax is [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)  t2 is not the same as t^2, which comes out as $t^2$

Comment: I think the correct notation is $$\frac{du}{dt}=2t$$ and so on which is generated by `$$\frac{du}{dt}=2t$$`.

Answer (score 2):

You answer is good and has simplified enough but since I don't know for what you want to simplify this may help you
$$t+2t\ln(4t)=t(1+2\ln(4t))=t(\ln e+\ln((4t)^2))=t\ln(16et^2).       $$

Answer (score 0):

It really can't be simplified much more. Your answer is good: $t+2t\ln(4t)$

Comment: Note: you can right-click on my formula and select "Show Math As >> TeX Commands" to see how you can type it in better, but I understood what you meant. Don't forget to surround math symbols with $ signs to indicate math mode.